# Good thumb up/down icons

Tags: web, vector, icons, pixel

I can't find any free thumb icons for voting like the ones here http://www.99points.info/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/youtube.jpg. Everything I find is too colored or detailed. Does anyone know a good website where I would find such icons or an icon set?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are www.99points.info bought or found the icons as well.  Very unlikely they developed an in house proprietary set.  You might consider contacting them to find out where to get similar icons.

Comment: They actually have those icons included in their download files but are very low quality and not png, as I would need

Comment: Converting to PNG is easy, any modern graphics editor should be able to do it.  Assuming you are just pulling this from their webpage, the server might be auto-scaling the icons.  Going to the source image linked in the image element should give the high resolution image.  You should ask them first though to ensure they are not proprietary, which by this point means you've contact them so you might as well find out where they got them from.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just make a screenshot copy/paste and save as png?
UPDATE: you can find a lot of good icons using http://www.iconfinder.com

Comment: well, there's no use saving as png if the icons won't have a transparent background. I'm trying to find original icons

Comment: There are many free editors where you can easily edit the background to be transparent. Under Windows, for example, there is paint.net. It is not hard at all. For additional info see the update on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original image..

[image: https://s.ytimg.com/yts/imgbin/www-hitchhiker-vflFMVkjB.png]

That's the youtube one at least. The one you want.